# Alphabetize methods in implementation file by name

Tags: xcode4

I am using XCode 4.
I have a very long .m file with a lot of function implementation.

I'd like to sort the functions alphabetically by their name or by its return type or the same order in its .h file.

The purpose of this is to better organize my .m file. I recently rearranged the functions in its corresponding .h file and it would be great if their is an automatic way of sorting the function implementation the same way its ordered in the .h

Here is an example of what I have now.

Currently have.

.h file

```
-(void) a;
-(void) b;
-(void) c;
```

.m file

```
-(void) c;
-(void) a;
-(void) b;
```

I'd like .m to sort the same way .h is sorted. I really hope this is possible without me copy pasting. The file is thousands of lines long.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it but while you are at it... if your file is "thousands of lines long" then maybe it's time for some refactoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot find a sorting function anywhere. But actually I find it more useful to group methods by its kind and use the pragma mark. E.g. all the MKMapViewDelegate methods come after the following pragma comment

```
#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate
```

This allows you to find methods more easily when you use the drop down right above the editor.

Apart from this the only best way to easily do the cut&paste job is to fold all the methods using menu **Editor -> Code Folding -> Fold Methods & Functions** as already pointed out by idz.

Also I would consider re-factoring of your class. Can you create several classes? Maybe you have utility methods that you can move into a general purpose utility class?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the code folding approach and using pragma marks. Once everything is organized I will most likely refactor this monstrosity I call a class :)

Answer (score 5):

If you hold down the command key while selecting the function popup in Xcode4 then the messages will be listed in alphabetical order.

Class messages(+) will be sorted before instance messages(-).

Comment: Nice tip, didn't know that one! @Farzad: You can also use "#pragma mark" to add some entries to better organize this menu too (and use "#pragma mark -" to add a separator in the menu)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a way of doing this automatically in Xcode, but the following may make doing it manually quicker. Open the implementation file. Then do **Editor > Code Folding > Fold Methods & Functions**. Now all your methods will have been folded down to one or two lines each, depending on your coding style. You can now select a function and drag it to its new position to achieve the ordering you want.

If you need to refer to the header file to ensure the order is correct, try doing this in the assistant view; that way you can see the header file and implementation file side by side.